# Read data from file C++

Tags: c++

I would like to extract the max values for each node but my program prints me just the max for node number 1 eight times:

**223
223
223
223
223
223
223
223**

Given the input data I expect to see:

**223
736
898
543
367
726
568
563**

[this is my textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqO2H.png)

Any help 
Thanks in advance

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
   template <typename T>
   string IntToString(T Number)
    {   stringstream ss;
      ss <<Number;
     return ss.str();
     }
int main() {
                ifstream ifs;
        ofstream ofs;
                double maxTxEnergy = 0;
                vector<double> TxE;
                double maxRxEnergy = 0;
                double FullTxEnergy = 0;
                double FullRxEnergy = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <=1; i++){    
        stringstream ss;
        ss <<i<<"00";
        string filename = ss.str();
        filename.append(".txt");
        ifs.open(filename.c_str());
        cout << "Analyzing: " << filename << endl;
        string filename1 = "Result/";
        filename1.append(filename);
        ofs.open(filename1.c_str());
        string str;     
 for (int j=1; j<=8; j++)
{
   string s = IntToString(j);
        while (!ifs.eof()) {
            getline (ifs, str);
 int a = str.find("transmission number  for node "+s+" is :");
 if (a != -1) {
                double TxEnergy = 0;
                istringstream iss(str.substr(a+62));
                iss >> TxEnergy;
                maxTxEnergy = TxEnergy;
                                if(maxTxEnergy<TxEnergy)
                                maxTxEnergy = TxEnergy; 
        }

  }
   TxE.push_back(maxTxEnergy);            

}
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = TxE.begin(); it != TxE.end (); it++)
   {
ofs << "Full transmission Energy: " << *it << endl; 
    }          
        ifs.close();
        ofs.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `maxTxEnergy = TxEnergy; if(maxTxEnergy<TxEnergy)  maxTxEnergy = TxEnergy; ` something is wrong is here. This if will never be true. Maybe you don't need the assignment before the if ?

Comment: Thanks Michel for your answer,but I think that the program is only verified for j = 1, and the result for j = 1 is shown 8 times.ie the loop for does not increment the value of j; can you help me to fixed this probleme

Comment: You can use std::to_string instead of IntToString, don't invent bicycle :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unformatted, I think you should remove this line

```
maxTxEnergy = TxEnergy;
```

Since this line makes `maxTxEnergy` to the last `TxEnergy` you read.